# How to determine the sign of R underlying R-squared?

Tags: correlation, r-squared

So we know that:

$$
R^{2}=\frac{SSR}{SSTO}
$$

If we want to know the  value of $R$, how do we know what the proper sign is?

Answer (score 9):

In multiple regression, $R$ represents the correlation between $\hat{y}$ and $y$, and as such is always non-negative.

e.g. see Wikipedia [on $R^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient)

> [...] $R^2$ equals the square of the Pearson correlation coefficient between the observed and modeled (predicted) data values of the dependent variable.

In simple regression you could regard $R$ as more than one thing (since $R^2$ can be seen meaningfully as the square of more than one correlation), in which case you need to say which thing you want. If you mean the correlation between $\hat{y}$ and $y$, that's still non-negative. If you mean the correlation between $y$ and $x$, the sign will be the same as the sign of the regression coefficient.

Comment: "represents the correlation squared" I think you mean

Comment: @Bill no, I mean what I have there in the first line -- $R$ is not the correlation squared. $R^2$ is the correlation squared.